# Transistor getting hot in rail splitter circuit

Tags: transistors, virtual-ground

I designed and prototyped the circuit below. The circuit works as expected but Q2 is getting really hot during operation. I simulated it in LTSpice and saw that Q2 draws more current but the range is in 700uA.

The input voltage in prototype is around 20V. What may be the reason for the increase in temperature of Q2?

[image: Circuit]

Comment: What load is connected and how did you wire your transistors?

Comment: What are the voltages across the transistor while it is getting hot?

Comment: Base is at 9.4V; emitter at 10V and collector is on ground. I did use regular breadboard and cables.

Comment: If there is current flowing into J2, then Q2 could get hot.  If you did not simulate that current, then it wouldn't show in your simulation.  Could you measure that current, or tell us what the load is out there?

Comment: Does your power supply show you how much current is going into VCC?  Is the other side of the load tied to Vee or Vss?  Is you load a resistor?  If so, you can compare the total amount of current flowing into the circuit vs the amount of current flowing into the load to see if there is excessive current through Q2,  or if you're just seeing the result of the load current going through Q2.

Comment: @TimWescott You are right. The J2 is supplying another op amp circuit. If totally disconnected there is no increase in temperature. I guess I created a load imbalance and Q2 draws more current to supply the circuit...

Comment: @newothegreat I guess there is a load imbalance between Q1 and Q2. I will try to measure the current.

Comment: @AnilB You'll need a little more design work for a reasonable power rail splitter. And I would definitely not use the LM741. I can post up something pretty quickly, as an example, if you want to see. (I'd like to know how much the split rail ground needs to sink or source to either rail, though.)

Comment: @jonk I will appreciate that. I plan to power +/- rails of 4 quad operational amplifiers (LM324SN). In addition positive rail will be connected to Arduino Nano and LCD screen (I estimate around 200mA)

Comment: Are the Arduino and LCD going to be connected to the output of the circuit shown here?  If so, that's probably the source of your heat.  All of that current will flow through Q2.  Since Q2 has 10V across it, and the load is 200mA, you're going to dissipate 2W on Q2 (10V * 0.2A = 2W)

Comment: @newothegreat you are exactly right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something close to what I'm thinking about. It's really not all that different from the usual class-AB power amplifier stage of an audio amplifier.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9NLq1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This circuit includes some details to handle BJT variations and using the Sziklai arrangement helps circumvent issues related to heating in the power BJTs, \$Q_1\$ and \$Q_2\$. You will need to adjust \$R_{14}\$ to set the quiescent current (just measure the voltage across \$R_1\$ or \$R_2\$ while setting this.) I've also included \$R_{13}\$ to handle the Early Effect of \$Q_5\$ and \$R_{16}\$ to deal with accidental shorts (you can remove it, if you want, by simply bypassing it with a wire.) \$R_9\$ and \$R_{10}\$ are there to avoid oscillation and to help match BJT vagaries. But they also can be removed (bypass them) if you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will give it a try tomorrow. Can you suggest an op amp?

Comment: @AnilB I like the LT1800 (since I have some handy.) Or the LT1797. But you don't need rail to rail I/O. Use something that is unity gain stable, of course.